# is it possible to create a variable for an endpoint response in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a function that depending on the button pressed, hits a different endpoint. However, these endpoints would have the same response, and return similar data. Is there a way to keep things DRY here instead of copying and pasting the response in an if else? Function below for reference.

```
    $scope.getModelRunJson = function (xOrY) {
        if(xOrY) {
            Runs.getData({id: $scope.runId}).then(
               function (response) {
                    $scope.runData = response.data.data[0].runData;
                    console.log($scope.modelRunData);

                    let blob = new Blob([$scope.runData], {type: 'json'});
                    let downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
                    downloadLink.attr('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                    downloadLink.attr('download', 'modelRun.json');
                    downloadLink[0].click();
                }
            )
        }
        else {
            Audit.getData({id: $scope.runId}).then(
                function (response) {
                    $scope.runData = response.data.data[0].runData;
                    console.log($scope.runData);

                    let blob = new Blob([$scope.runData], {type: 'json'});
                    let downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
                    downloadLink.attr('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
                    downloadLink.attr('download', 'modelRun.json');
                    downloadLink[0].click();
                }
            )
        }
    };
```

Comment: Would using the same function but with parameters for different buttons help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. `Runs` and `Audit` both implement `getData`

```js
$scope.getModelRunJson = function(xOrY) {
  const xy = (xOrY) ? Runs : Audit;
  xy.getData({
    id: $scope.runId
  }).then(
    function(response) {
      $scope.runData = response.data.data[0].runData;
      console.log($scope.modelRunData);

      let blob = new Blob([$scope.runData], {
        type: 'json'
      });
      let downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
      downloadLink.attr('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      downloadLink.attr('download', 'modelRun.json');
      downloadLink[0].click();
    }
  )

};
```